# Insertion of a raster geotiff in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, database

I am new in PostgreSQL and psql.
What is the method to insert a raster geotiff in a postgreSQL database using command psql? What is the best format? Someone indicates to save a raster image as BLOB format.

Comment: What is the size of your geotiff: 2GB or considerably larger? Moreover psql is not the best software for working with PostgreSQL database. Use Database Master 5 or pgAdmin 3

Answer (score 2):

I used this process recently through the cmd window (Windows 7):

- **Step 1:** Positionning inside raster2pgsql directory

  ```
  cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin
  ```
- **Step 2:** Generate SQL script (see options legend below)

  ```
  raster2pgsql -c -s 3947 -t 70x111 -N 0 -I "D:\myRaster.tif" schema.table > "D:\myRaster.sql"
  ```

  `-c` : create a new table in specified schema

  `-s` : SRID to be used (replace with yours)

  `-t` : raster size in columns x lines (open in QGIS for example and get this info from layer properties)

  `-N` : No-data pixels value (see also in QGIS > Layer properties)

  `-l` : creation of an index for rast column (special column for storing raster geometry)
- **Step3:** Script execution (can also be launched in a SQL window within pgAdmin III)

  ```
  psql -U userName -d dataBase -h host -f "D:\myRaster.sql"
  ```

This worked fine for me... You can check in QGIS if your raster was imported properly in your database (with DB Manager plugin for instance).

Hope this helps!